# Keep row height on animated flex boxes

Tags: css, animation, flexbox, css-animations

I'm using flex to display as set of divs and animating the images by setting their width to 95% on hover. This is my CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 0 1 48%;
}

.img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width ease-in 0.15s;
}

.img-container:hover img {
  width: 95%;
  transition: width ease-in 0.15s;
}
```

My problem is that, because of the animation duration, if I hover on images from the top row, for a brief moment both animations are active, forcing the row's height to decrease, which makes the elements beneath it bounce up and down.

Is there a way to force the row to keep its height constant during these animations?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 2%;
  flex: 0 1 48%;
}

.box:nth-of-type(2n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.img-container {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  animation: fadein 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width ease-in 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.img-container:hover img {
  width: 95%;
  transition: width ease-in 0.15s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x800?text=1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x800?text=2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x800?text=3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x800?text=4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/L5JxEiEyX2NyTHmSmlwS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You animate with `transform: scale()` instead. It will give you a much smoother animation and the other elements won't be affected.

```
.img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform ease-in 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.img-container:hover img {
  transform: scale(.95);
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 2%;
  flex: 0 1 48%;
}

.box:nth-of-type(2n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.img-container {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  animation: fadein 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform ease-in 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.img-container:hover img {
  transform: scale(.95);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x800?text=1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x800?text=2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x800?text=3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x800?text=4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```